# SQL Group Range Values

Tags: sql, group-by, range, gaps-and-islands

I have taken a look at several other questions/answers on here but I cannot apply those to my problem. I am trying to identify multiple sequential breaks based on a key column. Most examples I have found do not deal with multiple breaks in a sequence for the same key column.

```
Sample data:
Location     Number
------------------------
300          15
300          16
300          17
300          18
300          21
300          22
300          23
400          10
400          11
400          14
400          16

Here is the result I am looking for:
Location     StartNumber    StartNumber
------------------------------------------
300                   15             18
300                   21             23
400                   10             11
400                   14             14
400                   16             16
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's as relatively portable SQL solution since you didn't specify the DB

```
Create Table  SampleData  (Location int, Number Int)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (300, 15)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (300, 16)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (300, 17)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (300, 18)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (300, 21)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (300, 22)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (300, 23)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (400, 10)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (400, 11)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (400, 14)
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (400, 16)



SELECT 
        t1.Location,
        t1.Number      AS startofgroup, 
       MIN(t2.Number) AS endofgroup 
FROM   (SELECT Number , Location
        FROM   SampleData tbl1 
        WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                          FROM   SampleData tbl2 
                          WHERE  tbl1.Number - tbl2.Number = 1
                                 and tbl1.Location = tbl2.Location)) t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Number , Location
                   FROM   SampleData tbl1 
                   WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                                     FROM   SampleData tbl2 
                                     WHERE  tbl2.Number - tbl1.Number = 1
                                     and tbl1.Location = tbl2.Location)) t2 
         ON t1.Number <= t2.Number 
            and t1.Location = t2.Location
GROUP  BY 
    t1.Location,
    t1.Number 
ORDER BY 
   Location,
   startofgroup
```

Output

```
Location    startofgroup endofgroup
----------- ------------ -----------
300         15           18
300         21           23
400         10           11
400         14           14
400         16           16
```

Its a modified version of  Listing 2. A set-based solution for identifying islands. From [Islands and Gaps in Sequential Numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) by Alexander Kozak

If you're looking for more options with SQL Server 2005 and later you should search for the phrase "[Itzik Ben-Gan gaps and islands](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS392US392&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Itzik%20Ben-Gan%20gaps%20and%20islands)"

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using an RDBMS that supports the lag() function, then this should tell you where the breaks are.  You should then be able to use this, along with some case statements and careful use of the min() and max() functions, to get the query that you want.

```
select location, lag_number as startnumber, number as endnumber
from(select location, number, lag_number
from(
    select location, number
    , lag(number) over (partition by location order by number) as lag_number
    from table
    )a
    where number is not null and lag_number is not null
)b
where number-lag_number>1 order by 1,2,3;
```